# Writing a Google Sheets Query that can handle different text data types / dates?

Tags: function, google-sheets

I was asked to make a spreadsheet for a friend that initially seemed pretty easy, but I've run into one really tough formula I can't get to work properly. The goal is to query the "Date Ideas" tab to be able to find  all the events that would work with the specific bounds. "Location", "Distance", and "Rating Minimum" all work well, but not "Time".

To be as user friendly as possible, I'm trying to have it work for any data type. Right now those include day ranges (Any Day, Weekends, Weeknights), dates (09/25), and date ranges (09/19 - 09/29). I currently have them all as text so that year isn't a concern (but if you think of a good way to add that too, awesome!)

As the function currently works, a single date is the biggest thing not working. If I input "09/25" I correctly see "Any Night", "Weeknight", "Wednesday", and "09/25" ideas. However, ideas that take place from "09/19 - 09/29" don't appear. Previously, I had gotten it to appear, but when that was the case inputting something like "01/03" also showed ideas on "09/25" and "09/19 - 09/29". I've run out of ideas on extra things to add to get it work for every instan

I'm a big Google Sheets fan, especially it's Query function so that's how I put this together. If there's another method that would work way better (on Google Sheets), I'm open to hearing about it though! I don't have much experience with App Scripts if that's maybe a solution? Appreciate the help!

Spreadsheet Copy: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1knrZgMI4eGlfttFisFS2lr74qkxygY4PlLApQkGlOEQ/edit?usp=sharingce!

The Question specifically relates to cell 'Date Creator'!C10:

```
  =IFERROR(QUERY('Date Ideas'!C4:O,"SELECT C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K" 
  & IF(COUNTA(E4:E7)>0," WHERE ","")
  & IF(COUNTA(E4)=0,
     "",
     " (O CONTAINS '"&E4&"' OR O CONTAINS '"&IFERROR(ARRAYFORMULA(TEXT(DATEVALUE(LEFT(E4,5)) + SEQUENCE(1, DATEDIF(LEFT(E4,5),RIGHT(E4,5), "D") + 1, 0), "dddd")),"Err")&IF(AND(IFERROR(SEARCH("Friday",ARRAYFORMULA(TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,TEXT(DATEVALUE(LEFT(E4,5)) +SEQUENCE(1, DATEDIF(LEFT(E4,5),RIGHT(E4,5), "D") + 1, 0), "dddd")))),FALSE),IFERROR(SEARCH("Saturday",ARRAYFORMULA(TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,TEXT(DATEVALUE(LEFT(E4,5)) + SEQUENCE(1, DATEDIF(LEFT(E4,5),RIGHT(E4,5), "D") + 1, 0), "dddd")))),FALSE),IFERROR(SEARCH("Sunday",ARRAYFORMULA(TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,TEXT(DATEVALUE(LEFT(E4,5)) + SEQUENCE(1, DATEDIF(LEFT(E4,5),RIGHT(E4,5), "D") + 1, 0), "dddd"))))),FALSE),",Weekends","")&IF(AND(IFERROR(SEARCH("Monday",ARRAYFORMULA(TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,TEXT(DATEVALUE(LEFT(E4,5)) + SEQUENCE(1, DATEDIF(LEFT(E4,5),RIGHT(E4,5), "D") + 1, 0), "dddd")))),FALSE),IFERROR(SEARCH("Tuesday",ARRAYFORMULA(TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,TEXT(DATEVALUE(LEFT(E4,5)) + SEQUENCE(1, DATEDIF(LEFT(E4,5),RIGHT(E4,5), "D") + 1, 0), "dddd")))),FALSE),IFERROR(SEARCH("Wednesday",ARRAYFORMULA(TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,TEXT(DATEVALUE(LEFT(E4,5)) + SEQUENCE(1, DATEDIF(LEFT(E4,5),RIGHT(E4,5), "D") + 1, 0), "dddd")))),FALSE),IFERROR(SEARCH("Thursday",ARRAYFORMULA(TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,TEXT(DATEVALUE(LEFT(E4,5)) + SEQUENCE(1, DATEDIF(LEFT(E4,5),RIGHT(E4,5), "D") + 1, 0), "dddd"))))),FALSE),",Weekdays","")&"')"
  )
  & IF(AND(COUNTA(E4)>0,REGEXMATCH(E4,"/")),
     ARRAYFORMULA(TEXTJOIN("'",TRUE," AND NOT O CONTAINS '"&FILTER(Constants!C14:C,Constants!C14:C<>E4,Constants!C14:C<>"")))&"'",
     "")
  & IF(COUNTA(E5)>0,
     IF(COUNTA(E4)>0,"AND ",""),
     "")
  & IF(COUNTA(E5)>0,
     "G='"&E5&"' ",
     "")
  & IF(COUNTA(E6)>0,
     IF(OR(COUNTA(E4)>0,COUNTA(E5)>0),"AND ",""),
     "")
  & IF(COUNTA(E6)>0,
     "H='"&E6&"' ",
     "")
  &IF(E7="","",IF(OR(COUNTA(E4)>0,COUNTA(E5)>0,COUNTA(E6)>0),"AND ",""))
  &IF(E7="","",IF(E7="","","I>="))
  &IF(E7="","",IF(E7="","",E7))
  &" LIMIT 5"),
  "None")
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). I took a look at your spreadsheet and it isn't clear what formula you are talking about.  Wherever possible questions should be self-contained. Include the problem formula in your question, and what is/isn't working.